shell_exec does not support 24bits nor 8 bits color mode
I'm running a command with shell_exec from ascii-image-converter
(https://github.com/TheZoraiz/ascii-image-converter)
which return
<?php
$cmd = "ascii-image-converter $fichier -s ./assets/images/ascii $width $negative $color --only-save -c";
$output=shell_exec($cmd);
?>
Error: your terminal supports neither 24-bit nor 8-bit colors. Other coloring options aren't available

But when i run this specific command on my bash it work
This is my own server so i can configure it as i want.
Any ideas ?

We'd need a [mcve] in order to duplicate and understand the problem. Please edit your question with code that is NOT working as well as thinking about "can readers duplicate this with a diferent file than one I have?". Good luck.

The user that runs the web server usually doesn't have shell access, so it wouldn't have access to a termColorLevel, or any other term settings.

There is catimg and all tools using libaa and libcaca.

The color is denoted by special terminal control codes, and those codes depend on the terminal emulator in use. The converter is trying to detect the terminal type is failing because there isn't one. The only solution would be to "fake" a terminal, but then the generated file would only work when viewed in a matching terminal emulator, or you would have to implement something to translate the control codes to make the colors work in something else. What are you planning to do with the generated file?

Does the tool do this even when you don't ask for color? If so, you can do env TERM=xterm-256color ascii-image-converter ... (If not, then don't do this, and instead don't ask for color)

I've been trying that program and it works flawlessly for me through shell_exec(), but I had to apply a few guesses to the command and arguments because your question omits them. If your intention is to save output as PNG file, you shouldn't need a console. Can you please edit the question and show the exact value of the $cmd variable?
